# perl Facebook::Graph API check if user likes page

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [Facebook::Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::Graph) and any time a page is loaded, I would like to detect server-side if a user has liked a certain page or not. I can't find in the documentation how to do this though. Is it possible to do this without sending the user ID to my server-side script? Because I know using the javascript SDK you can check this, but I feel like it might be different with a server-side API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "anytime a page is loaded"... I guess you mean an page of an App? If so, you need the `user_likes` permission to be able to get the information on the User's likes.

If you're using a Page Tab App, then you could get this info out of the `signed_request` which is passed to the App once the User accesses it from the Facebook Page Tab. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/ The indicator is in the `page.liked` field.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was confused how apps were determining if I had liked a page or not even though I had not given them permission, but it must've been because they were all page tab apps.