# Facebook app user likes without big red alert

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm making the Facebook app whit JavaScript SDK, and I need user likes permissions to make a like gate. When I go to my app for the first time I get the popup whit permissions and big red alert: "The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: user_likes " When I submit my permissions for approvement they reject me... Is there another way to make a like gate?[image: IMG]

Comment: I think the real issue here might be "why are they rejecting it?"

Comment: You are not allowed to use user_likes for like-gating. You can do like-gating in page tab apps using the liked-value in signed_request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having a Page Tab App, then use the signed_request data. If not then you'll need the permission to be able to access the User's likes.

Have a look at my answer here: [perl Facebook::Graph API check if user likes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730048/perl-facebookgraph-api-check-if-user-likes-page/23731187#23731187)

Comment: Yes I have a Page Tab App. Can you give me example how to do that?