# Cookies that can remember facebook users who liked

Tags: facebook, wordpress, popupwindow

I am fresh and making a plugin pop up facebook like box from sketches so please can any body guide me, how I can use cookies to detect if user has already like my facebook page, and don't show the box to him other wise if he hasn't like the page show it.

Comment: How do you know if someone liked something in the first place?

Comment: ofcourse I am creating a facebook popup like box, I want to use cookies to store data and don't open it again if user like the page. I know what exactly you are taking about but I dont want to go in complicated method to make app and ask permission from users rather Its ok to use cookies.

Comment: But to put something in a cookie you need to know if the user liked the page or not. How will you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're heading in a wrong direction. I guess what you want to implement is a so-called "Fan Gate". This was already answered a lot of times here on SO, for example see [perl Facebook::Graph API check if user likes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730048/perl-facebookgraph-api-check-if-user-likes-page/23731187#23731187)

If you're using a Page Tab App, this is the way to go. Otherwise you'll be having problems to determine whether the specific user has liked you page or not, because you don't have the `user_likes` permission, which is necessary to get this info.

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-traffic-pop-for-wordpress/150963?WT.ac=search_item&WT.oss_phrase=facebook%20traffic%20pop&WT.oss_rank=1&WT.z_author=TylerQuinn|

I want something like above in the feature it state that "Cookies remember users who already ‘Liked’ the page"
so how he is using cookies to remember likes ?

Comment: FB doesn't store page like data in cookies afaik. Fan Gates are normally done via the way I described.